# apply a function to some columns of a data frame, while storing the result in the original data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame, where I would like to render some of the columns as factor (at the moment they are numeric).

For example:

```
dd = data_frame( x = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

I would like to make only the first column a factor:

```
lapply(dd[,1], as.factor)
```

But the result is a list (of a factor), and is not saved back to the original data frame.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: you can do `dd[1] <- lapply(dd[1], as.factor)`

Comment: what if I want to do this for several columns?

Comment: `dd[1:4] <- lapply(dd[1:4], as.factor)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
dd <- dd %>%
         mutate(x = factor(x))
```

Or for multiple columns

```
nm1 <- names(dd)[1:2]
dd <- dd %>%
        mutate_at(vars(nm1), factor)
```

---

In the OP's code, the issue is that it is looping through the first column elements into a `list`.  Instead, we need just

```
dd[,1] <- factor(dd[,1])
```

Or

```
dd[[1]] <- factor(dd[[1]])
```

NOTE: For a single column, we don't need any `lapply`

If we want to apply to multiple columns

```
dd[nm1] <- lapply(dd[nm1], factor)
```

Comment: But this would apply to all the columns of dd. I only want some of the columns to become factor